# Invisible Directory

Tags: filesystems, macos

My system is a MacOS Monterey. I have accidentally created an invisible directory in my conda environments folder. The directory is not visible even with `ls -a`. I can list the directory with the absolute path though!

How do I undo this ? i.e. make the directory listable again ?

Supporting screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I see a `ML` directory right there in your `ls` output. Are you confused by the fact that Mac OS normalizes the case of names?

Comment: also, please don't use unrelated tags. This is specifically **not** about [tag:Linux]!

Comment: The question I have closed this as a duplicate of is not an _exact_ duplicate, but the cause is identical: your macOS system has a case-insensitive filesystem. This is evident of the fact that `cd ml` takes you to your `ML` directory.